# ExtJS4 store, filter 1 field by multiple values

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Say i have a some store with some data:

`id value`
`1  one`
`2  two`
`3  three`
`4  four`

and i'd like to filter it by ID like:
`store.filter("id", "[1, 4]");`

Is it possible?
Is there also an another way to get a few values from store by `id`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
store.filter(function(r) {
    var value = r.get('id');
    return (value == 1 || value == 4);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

store.addFilter({property: 'id', value: [1,4], operator: 'in'});